# Kernel Confusion

Tags: kernel-trick, feature-engineering

Consider the function $K(\vec{x},\vec{y})$ where $\vec{x},\vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I have been asked to check that this is a valid kernel.

**Question 1**

My understanding is that I can prove this in one of two ways:

1, I can show there exists a feature map $\phi : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ such that $K(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) = \langle \vec{\phi}(\vec{x}), \vec{\phi}(\vec{y}) \rangle$

2, I can show that $K(\vec{x},\vec{y})$ is positive semi-definite

Is my understanding correct here that these are both valid ways to show something is a kernel?

**Question 2**

Let's suppose I want to explicitly show positive semi-definiteness (as in case 2 above). I am unsure whether I do this by showing

(a) $K(\vec{a}, \vec{a}) \geq 0$

This case is kind of appealing since kernels are supposed to measure similarity between two vectors and so it only really makes sense for a vector to have a similarity with itself that is $\geq 0$.

(b) $\vec{a}^T K(\vec{x},\vec{y}) \vec{a} \geq 0$

In this case $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ define the kernel matrix and I need to show it is a positive semi-definite matrix for any other vector $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n$

I'd appreciate any help with my understanding on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q1, you can prove both way. First approach is typically harder since you explicitly need to find a high dimensional representation (that may also be non-unique).

For Q2, there is no such thing like $K(a,a)$ in general because $a\in R^N$ where $K(x,y)$ is of $N\times N$ ($N$ is number of elements in the dataset), and $x,y\in R^n$, where $n$ is the dimension of the inner product space where your data lies. So, you'll need to make sure your kernel matrix has no negative eigenvalues, i.e. PSD property.

Comment: Yes, the combination. Because $K(x,y)$ will always be a scalar for any given $x,y$ pair (i.e. it is an inner product after all).

Comment: It's a general vector for showing semi-definiteness of $K$. The goal is to show the PSD property. If you have $K$, you can also find its eigenvalues and show that all of them are non-negative. There are various ways, $a$ is only a tool for showing it, with no special meaning to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful!